# Catch the event when the search of findcontrol is launched

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

I have a devexpress gridcontrol with a find option.
I want to catch the event when the search of findcontrol is launched, to force the display, in the form.

I found this function , but it works only in the lostFocus event:

```
private void gridView1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pFindPanel = gridView1.GetType().GetProperty("FindPanel", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    FindControl findPanel = (FindControl)pFindPanel.GetValue(gridView1, null);

    Point pt = gridControl1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    if ((!findPanel.Bounds.Contains(pt)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Do!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ColumnView.ColumnFilterChanged`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ColumnFilterChangedtopic) event. In this event you can check for the value of [`ColumnView.FindFilterText`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FindFilterTexttopic) property and display this value in the form.
Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string findFilter = gridView1.FindFilterText;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(findFilter))
        MessageBox.Show(findFilter);
}
```